# "Subquery returned more than 1 value" - Received when trying to create a stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, subquery

I have been having some issues creating a stored procedure, the procedure adds records into a temp table.

I am getting the above error message, not when I try to execute the procedure but when first trying to create it. I have checked every sub-query within the statement and it looks OK because they are set to top 1 and only return one value. I also commented out the sub-selects and replaced them with a hard-coded values but this still gave the same error.

How can it be that when there are no sub query's that it returns this error?

I have looked at the other answers on here but they seem to be directly related to sub-query's returning more than one value which in this case isn't happening.

```
-- Drop stored procedure if it already exists
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
   WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
     AND SPECIFIC_NAME = N'PLO_CreateExchanges' 
)
   DROP PROCEDURE dbo.PLO_CreateExchanges
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PLO_CreateExchanges
    @FirstExchange DATETIME, 
    @EndDate DATETIME, 
    @StartDate DATETIME, 
    @Frequency INT, 
    @AgreementID INT
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ExchangeDate DATETIME
   DECLARE @NumberOfExchanges INT
   DECLARE @ExchangeQty INT
--Data


WHILE @ExchangeDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN


IF @ExchangeDate >= @StartDate
BEGIN
--Do something
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Orders

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
--Create Table
        SELECT  *
        INTO    #Orders
        FROM    dbo.Orders
        WHERE   id < 0
        ALTER TABLE dbo.#Orders
        DROP COLUMN id
END

SET @AgreementID = 1

        INSERT  INTO #Orders
                                (AgreementID ,
                                 TransType ,
                                 StartDate ,
                                 EndDate ,
                                 JobNumber ,
                                 AddressID ,
                                 DeliveryAddressID ,
                                 AreaID ,
                                 ProductTypeID ,
                                 InternalNoteID ,
                                 CollectionTime ,
                                 ContainerTypeID ,
                                 DeliveryContainerID ,
                                 CollectionContainerID ,
                                 NetCharge ,
                                 SpecialPrice ,
                                 VehicleID ,
                                 DisposalSiteID ,
                                 DisposalCharge ,
                                 DisposalTicket ,
                                 OnRoad ,
                                 Authorisation1 ,
                                 Authorisation2 ,
                                 Weighed ,
                                 Printed ,
                                 InvoiceNumber ,
                                 InvoiceDate ,
                                 WeighbridgeTransactionID ,
                                 RouteID ,
                                 RouteSequence ,
                                 Quantity ,
                                 Activity ,
                                 ContactPerson ,
                                 ContactTime ,
                                 Notes1 ,
                                 Notes2 ,
                                 Notes3 ,
                                 InvoiceMethodID ,
                                 ScheduledDate ,
                                 Extracted ,
                                 AdditionalCharge ,
                                 AdditionalChargeDesc ,
                                 ScheduledSiteID ,
                                 ChargedBy ,
                                 Weight ,
                                 HaulierID ,
                                 AllocationCode ,
                                 ConsignmentNumber ,
                                 PreNoteNumber ,
                                 Drums ,
                                 HaulageCharge ,
                                 Rate ,
                                 Manual ,
                                 Hours ,
                                 CurrencyID ,
                                 Confirmed ,
                                 Paid ,
                                 VehicleTypeID ,
                                 QuotationID ,
                                 ContractID ,
                                 ScheduledTypeID ,
                                 TempField1 ,
                                 TempField2 ,
                                 PaymentID ,
                                 EWCID ,
                                 DisposalCost ,
                                 Hold ,
                                 SalesID ,
                                 Cost ,
                                 CostSpecial ,
                                 HaulageCost ,
                                 MobileStatus ,
                                 Scheduled ,
                                 Complete ,
                                 SiteMobileStatus ,
                                 ContainerPriceID ,
                                 WeighbridgePriceID ,
                                 OriginalQuantity ,
                                 MissedEmail ,
                                 DateTimeLastUpdated ,
                                 LastUpdatedBy ,
                                 IsDeleted)
                                SELECT  @AgreementID , -- AgreementID - int
                                        'D' , -- TransType - char(2)
                                        A.StartDate , -- StartDate - datetime
                                        A.StartDate , -- EndDate - datetime
                                        NULL , -- JobNumber - int
                                        A.AddressID , -- AddressID - int
                                        A.DeliveryAddressID , -- DeliveryAddressID - int
                                        A.AreaCodeID , -- AreaID - int
                                        A.ProductTypeID , -- ProductTypeID - int
                                        A.InternalNoteID , -- InternalNoteID - int
                                        A.DropTime , -- CollectionTime - datetime
                                        A.ContainerTypeID , -- ContainerTypeID - int
                                        NULL , -- DeliveryContainerID - int
                                        NULL , -- CollectionContainerID - int
                                        A.DeliveryCharge , -- NetCharge - decimal
                                        A.SpecialPrice , -- SpecialPrice - bit
                                        A.DefaultDeliveryVehicleID , -- VehicleID - int
                                        A.DisposalSiteID , -- DisposalSiteID - int
                                        NULL , -- DisposalCharge - decimal
                                        NULL , -- DisposalTicket - nvarchar(30)
                                        A.OnRoad , -- OnRoad - bit
                                        A.Authorisation1 , -- Authorisation1 - nvarchar(50)
                                        A.Authorisation2 , -- Authorisation2 - nvarchar(50)
                                        0 , -- Weighed - bit
                                        0 , -- Printed - bit
                                        0 , -- InvoiceNumber - int
                                        NULL , -- InvoiceDate - datetime
                                        NULL , -- WeighbridgeTransactionID - int
                                        A.DeliveryRoute , -- RouteID - int
                                        NULL , -- RouteSequence - int
                                        1 , -- Quantity - int
                                        NULL , -- Activity - nvarchar(10)
                                        A.ContactPerson , -- ContactPerson - nvarchar(250)
                                        A.ContactTime , -- ContactTime - datetime
                                        A.Notes1 , -- Notes1 - nvarchar(350)
                                        A.Notes2 , -- Notes2 - nvarchar(350)
                                        A.Notes3 , -- Notes3 - nvarchar(350)
                                        A.InvoiceMethodID , -- InvoiceMethodID - int
                                        A.StartDate , -- ScheduledDate - datetime
                                        0 , -- Extracted - bit
                                        (SELECT CASE WHEN A.ApplyToDelivery = 1 THEN A.AdditionalCharge
                                                     ELSE 0
                                                END) , -- AdditionalCharge - decimal
                                        (SELECT CASE WHEN A.ApplyToDelivery = 1 THEN A.AdditionalFor
                                                     ELSE NULL
                                                END) , -- AdditionalChargeDesc - nvarchar(350)
                                        A.SiteID , -- ScheduledSiteID - int
                                        'V' , -- ChargedBy - char(1)
                                        NULL , -- Weight - decimal
                                        A.HaulierID , -- HaulierID - int
                                        NULL , -- AllocationCode - nvarchar(50)
                                        NULL , -- ConsignmentNumber - nvarchar(50)
                                        NULL , -- PreNoteNumber - nvarchar(50)
                                        NULL , -- Drums - int
                                        NULL , -- HaulageCharge - decimal
                                        NULL , -- Rate - decimal
                                        0 , -- Manual - bit
                                        NULL , -- Hours - decimal
                                        NULL , -- CurrencyID - int
                                        0 , -- Confirmed - bit
                                        0 , -- Paid - bit
                                        (SELECT TOP 1
                                                VehicleTypeID
                                         FROM   dbo.Vehicles V
                                         WHERE  id = A.DefaultDeliveryVehicleID AND V.IsDeleted = 0) , -- VehicleTypeID - int
                                        0 , -- QuotationID - int
                                        0 , -- ContractID - int
                                        (SELECT TOP 1
                                                ScheduleTypeID
                                         FROM   dbo.ContainerTypes CT
                                         WHERE  id = A.ContainerTypeID AND CT.IsDeleted = 0) , -- ScheduledTypeID - int
                                        A.TempField1 , -- TempField1 - nvarchar(250)
                                        A.TempField2 , -- TempField2 - nvarchar(250)
                                        NULL , -- PaymentID - int
                                        (SELECT TOP 1
                                                EWCID
                                         FROM   dbo.ProductCodes PC
                                         WHERE  id = A.ProductTypeID AND PC.IsDeleted = 0) , -- EWCID - int
                                        NULL , -- DisposalCost - decimal
                                        0 , -- Hold - bit
                                        A.SalesPersonID , -- SalesID - int
                                        NULL , -- Cost - decimal
                                        0 , -- CostSpecial - bit
                                        NULL , -- HaulageCost - decimal
                                        0 , -- MobileStatus - int
                                        1 , -- Scheduled - bit
                                        0 , -- Complete - bit
                                        NULL , -- SiteMobileStatus - int
                                        0 , -- ContainerPriceID - int
                                        0 , -- WeighbridgePriceID - int
                                        A.Quantity , -- OriginalQuantity - int
                                        NULL , -- MissedEmail - nvarchar(50)
                                        GETDATE() , -- DateTimeLastUpdated - datetime
                                        A.LastUpdatedBy , -- LastUpdatedBy - int
                                        0  -- IsDeleted - bit
                                FROM    dbo.Agreements A
                                WHERE   id = @AgreementID AND A.IsDeleted = 0



END


SET @ExchangeDate = DATEADD(d,7*@Frequency,@ExchangeDate)



END

END
```

Edit: The following code only works when you remove the commented rows, otherwise it still gives the same error, indicating that it is nothing to do with sub-selects:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]

AS
BEGIN


INSERT INTO dbo.[Order]
        (
        AgreementID 
  --       TransType ,
  --       StartDate ,
  --       EndDate ,
  --       JobNumber ,
  --       AddressID ,
  --       DeliveryAddressID ,
  --       AreaID ,
  --       ProductTypeID ,
  --       InternalNoteID ,
  --       CollectionTime ,
  --       ContainerTypeID ,
  --       DeliveryContainerID ,
  --       CollectionContainerID ,
  --       NetCharge ,
  --       SpecialPrice ,
  --       VehicleID ,
  --       DisposalSiteID ,
  --       DisposalCharge ,
  --       DisposalTicket ,
  --       OnRoad ,
  --       Authorisation1 ,
  --       Authorisation2 ,
  --       Weighed ,
  --       Printed ,
  --       InvoiceNumber ,
  --       InvoiceDate ,
  --       WeighbridgeTransactionID ,
  --       RouteID ,
  --       RouteSequence ,
  --       Quantity ,
  --       Activity ,
  --       ContactPerson ,
  --       ContactTime ,
  --       Notes1 ,
  --       Notes2 ,
  --       Notes3 ,
  --       InvoiceMethodID ,
  --       ScheduledDate ,
  --       Extracted ,
  --       AdditionalCharge ,
  --       AdditionalChargeDesc ,
  --       ScheduledSiteID ,
  --       ChargedBy ,
  --       [Weight] ,
  --       HaulierID ,
  --       AllocationCode ,
  --       ConsignmentNumber ,
  --       PreNoteNumber ,
  --       Drums ,
  --       HaulageCharge ,
  --       Rate ,
  --       [Manual] ,
  --       [Hours] ,
  --       CurrencyID ,
  --       Confirmed ,
  --       Paid ,
  --       VehicleTypeID ,
  --       QuotationID ,
  --       ContractID ,
  --       ScheduledTypeID ,
  --       TempField1 ,
  --       TempField2 ,
  --       PaymentID ,
  --       EWCID ,
  --       DisposalCost ,
  --       Hold ,
  --       SalesID ,
  --       Cost ,
  --       CostSpecial ,
  --       HaulageCost ,
  --       MobileStatus ,
  --       Scheduled ,
  --       Complete ,
  --       SiteMobileStatus ,
  --       ContainerPriceID ,
  --       WeighbridgePriceID ,
  --       OriginalQuantity ,
  --       MissedEmail ,
  --       DateTimeLastUpdated ,
  --       LastUpdatedBy ,
  --       IsDeleted
         )
VALUES (
 1
 -- AgreementID - int
--         '' , -- TransType - char(2)
--         GETDATE() , -- StartDate - datetime
--         GETDATE() , -- EndDate - datetime
--         0 , -- JobNumber - int
--         0 , -- AddressID - int
--         0 , -- DeliveryAddressID - int
--         0 , -- AreaID - int
--         0 , -- ProductTypeID - int
--         0 , -- InternalNoteID - int
--         GETDATE() , -- CollectionTime - datetime
--         0 , -- ContainerTypeID - int
--         0 , -- DeliveryContainerID - int
--         0 , -- CollectionContainerID - int
--         1.1 , -- NetCharge - decimal
--         0 , -- SpecialPrice - bit
--         0 , -- VehicleID - int
--         0 , -- DisposalSiteID - int
--         1.1 , -- DisposalCharge - decimal
--         N'' , -- DisposalTicket - nvarchar(30)
--         0 , -- OnRoad - bit
--         N'' , -- Authorisation1 - nvarchar(50)
--         N'' , -- Authorisation2 - nvarchar(50)
--         0 , -- Weighed - bit
--         0 , -- Printed - bit
--         0 , -- InvoiceNumber - int
--         GETDATE() , -- InvoiceDate - datetime
--         0 , -- WeighbridgeTransactionID - int
--         0 , -- RouteID - int
--         0 , -- RouteSequence - int
--         0 , -- Quantity - int
--         N'' , -- Activity - nvarchar(10)
--         N'' , -- ContactPerson - nvarchar(250)
--         GETDATE() , -- ContactTime - datetime
--         N'' , -- Notes1 - nvarchar(350)
--         N'' , -- Notes2 - nvarchar(350)
--         N'' , -- Notes3 - nvarchar(350)
--         0 , -- InvoiceMethodID - int
--         GETDATE() , -- ScheduledDate - datetime
--         0 , -- Extracted - bit
--         1.1 , -- AdditionalCharge - decimal
--         N'' , -- AdditionalChargeDesc - nvarchar(350)
--         0 , -- ScheduledSiteID - int
--         '' , -- ChargedBy - char(1)
--         1.1 , -- Weight - decimal
--         0 , -- HaulierID - int
--         N'' , -- AllocationCode - nvarchar(50)
--         N'' , -- ConsignmentNumber - nvarchar(50)
--         N'' , -- PreNoteNumber - nvarchar(50)
--         0 , -- Drums - int
--         1.1 , -- HaulageCharge - decimal
--         1.1 , -- Rate - decimal
--         0 , -- Manual - bit
--         1.1 , -- Hours - decimal
--         0 , -- CurrencyID - int
--         0 , -- Confirmed - bit
--         0 , -- Paid - bit
--         0 , -- VehicleTypeID - int
--         0 , -- QuotationID - int
--         0 , -- ContractID - int
--         0 , -- ScheduledTypeID - int
--         N'' , -- TempField1 - nvarchar(250)
--         N'' , -- TempField2 - nvarchar(250)
--         0 , -- PaymentID - int
--         0 , -- EWCID - int
--         1.1 , -- DisposalCost - decimal
--         0 , -- Hold - bit
--         0 , -- SalesID - int
--         1.1 , -- Cost - decimal
--         0 , -- CostSpecial - bit
--         1.1 , -- HaulageCost - decimal
--         0 , -- MobileStatus - int
--         0 , -- Scheduled - bit
--         0 , -- Complete - bit
--         0 , -- SiteMobileStatus - int
--         0 , -- ContainerPriceID - int
--         0 , -- WeighbridgePriceID - int
--         0 , -- OriginalQuantity - int
--         N'' , -- MissedEmail - nvarchar(50)
--         GETDATE() , -- DateTimeLastUpdated - datetime
--         0 , -- LastUpdatedBy - int
--         0  -- IsDeleted - bit
         )
END
```

Comment: I copied your code, added `USE MyDatabase` statement and stored procedure was created successfully.

Comment: It didn't complain that you have no agreements table?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I commented out all the code in the select into apart from agreementID. It still gave the error until I removed the commented code. As soon as I added in the commented part I had the error again. I had another developer try this with the same results.

Comment: @connersz - Often, views and stored procedures aren't validated that way until actually run because there are use cases where the table doesn't exist until (shortly before) then.  Say, a sp where it creates a temp table with some data, then selects from it...  You don't need the `SELECT` in `SELECT CASE ...`.  `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` is meaningless - either you have multiple rows, and need to order them first, or you have only one row, and could just do a regular join.  Statement works as-is in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3a22/4/0) (minus leading spaces).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Regardless of opinions. It doesn't work without the loop anyway.

Comment: create an [SQLFiddle](http://SQLFiddle.com) with some schema that will allow the proc to compile, and/or prune the SQL down to the bare minimum that still shows the problem. As it stands, 95% of the SQL is irrelevant and just "noise".

Comment: do you need SELECT on those case statements?

Comment: @misterManager it doesn't matter anyway. If I remove them it doesn't work still, see my new example of what doesn't work.

Comment: Please see my new example where I have commented most of the code and removed a lot of other stuff and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm playing around w/ sql fiddle now.... sql server 2012 or 2008?

Comment: I'm not getting an error on the second code sample you've provided when I uncomment everything. I'm going to work off the original and see what I can do

Comment: I've got to agree with @Serg.... when I used your original with a USE statement it worked just fine.

Comment: It's clear to us here that something is going on with the comments but not sure what. The comments after the data-to-insert are generated by sql prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 suggestions and hope it will helps.

1) Check the rowcount return from the query

```
Select * FROM
dbo.Agreements A
WHERE   id = 1 AND A.IsDeleted = 0
```

If there is only a row , then it should be fine.

If there is more than 1 row or no rows are returned, then it will be an issue in your select query because of the inconsistency of your columns' values. It is supposed to have 1 value for each column, it cant be one value for a column but 2 for another.

2)  If there is more than a row then you might need to add "`TOP 1`" at the beginning of your SELECT query that you intent to insert into `#Orders` temp table. But still you might need to cleanse the unwanted rows if duplication or dirty data are brought into your Agreements table.